# react router's route changing url but not loading the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a react website, the problem that is coming is that when I use `<Route>` to a specific component it appear in the URL but the component does not load. The compiler and console don't show any error. And I have published the website on Netlify and when I click a the link from there it says **"Page Not Found"
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.**
I am using react-router-dom version 6

The codes are:

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/About'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio'
import './App.scss'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

reportWebVitals()
```

SideBar/Navbar

```
import './index.scss'
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {
  faLinkedin,
  faGithub,
  faYoutube,
  faSkype,
} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faHome, faUser, faEnvelope, faSuitcase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="nav-bar">
      <Link className="logo" to="/">
        <img className="sub-logo" src={LogoSubtitle} alt="h" />
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="active" className="about-link" to="/about">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="active" className="portfolio-link" to="/portfolio">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSuitcase} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          activeclassname="active"
          className="contact-link"
          to="/contact"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.linkedin.com"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://github.com"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.youtube.com"
            rel="noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="skype" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSkype} color="#4d4d4e" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Layout

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';
import './index.scss';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className='App' >
      <Sidebar />
      <div className='page' >
        <span className='tags top-tags'>&lt;body&gt;</span>
        <Outlet />
        <span className='tags bottom-tags'>
          &lt;body&gt;
          <br />
          <span className='bottom-tag-html'>&lt;/html&gt;</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Please review the `create-react-app` deployment [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify) for netlify to see if you've missed any steps/settings/etc.

Comment: The route does not show component even in the localhost ... It shows a blank page

Comment: Not working locally? I don't see any overt issues in the code snippets. How are you running the app locally? Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this routing/navigation/rendering issue that we can inspect and debug live?